# android.hardware.telephony can this be added to devices

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, uri, android-package-managers

I have a feature that uses the `tel://` URI in an intent, this would launch phone apps and also give the choice of using the built in phone, so for devices without cellular signal I put in a condition to check

`if(pm.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.telephony"))` where `pm` is PackageManager object.

Some devices will crash if this condition is not there, despite being able to install the app based on manifest permissions.

But there are also VOIP apps which will take the `tel://` intent but don't actually use the telephony hardware.

is there a way I can check to see if the user's device has something that can use the tel URI instead of checking what hardware features they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the system has any activities that can receive the intent like so:

```
private void tryOpenDialer(String phoneNumber) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        // invalid input - return or throw IllegalArgumentException
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    PackageManager pkgManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pkgManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (activities.size() > 0) {
        context.startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        // if you want, pop up a toast or dialog telling the user there is
        // nothing on the device to handle this action
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, and all devices with a built in phone app will also respond to this query correct?

Comment: If there's any activity on the device that can resolve the intent, it should hit the line `context.startActivity(intent)`. The built-in phone app will do it, but other apps may do it as well (perhaps the user has replaced their dialer activity with one from the Play Store, for instance). Basically, you avoid calling startActivity until you've determined that there's some other app on the device that will be able to receive it.